# Xamarin.Android: Receive View and Send actions in an already running instance of an App (LaunchMode is SingleTop)

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, oncreate, launchmode, onnewintent

I want my app to be a viewer and send target for PDFs but don't want it to create new instances everytime. How do I catch the view intent action in my `MainActivity`? I tried `OnNewIntent()` but it doesn't get called. Only if the app wasn't already running, I get the action in `OnCreate()`. What am I missing?

```
[Activity (Theme = "@style/MainTheme", Label = "MyPdfViewer", Icon = "@drawable/icon", /*MainLauncher = true, --> SplashActivity is now the MainLauncher */LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = @"application/pdf")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = @"application/pdf")]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        LoadApplication (new App ());

        // handle clipboard data "send to" or "view document" actions
        if (Intent.Type == "application/pdf")
        {
            HandleSendOrViewAction();
        }

    }

    protected virtual void OnNewIntent()
    {
        var data = this.Intent.Data;  // <-- never called
        // do similar thing like in HandleSendOrViewAction()
    }

    private bool HandleSendOrViewAction()
    {
        // Get the info from ClipData 
        var pdf = Intent.ClipData.GetItemAt(0);

        // Open a stream from the URI 
        byte[] bytes;
        Stream inputStream;
        if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
            inputStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(pdf.Uri);
        else if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionView)
            inputStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Intent.Data);
        else
            return false;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            inputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        Services.PdfReceiver.Base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);  

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is the launch mode for your SplashScreen?

Answer (score 0):

> but don't want it to create new instances everytime.

The `standard` and `singleTop` of Launch Mode would create multiple instances. if you do not want create instance every time, you could use `singleTask` and `singleInstance` instead.

For `singleTop` Launch Mode, you need to know, if an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its `onNewIntent()` method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity. If the instance of the activity which already exists is not at the top, it would not call `onNewIntent()` method.

That's why i suggest to use `singleTask`. The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I experimented with SingleTask as well but it doesn't receive a ``OnNewIntent()`` as well. I noticed that this was an ``override`` in earlier Xamarin.Android versions and now it's a ``virtual``. Is it possible that the ``OnNewIntent()`` doesn't get call in certain cases? ``SingleTask`` seemed too destructive to me to use it (though when I tried it, it didn't replace the running activity at all, which was unexpected).

Comment: The ideal case would be that the app just receives the pdf and seamlessly handles the incoming data in a Xamarin.Forms page without destroying anything -- just adding the pdf to a list, for example. I thought about just allowing a new instance to be created, store the pdf in isolated storage, and use an uri for opening my app where I read the file from isolated storage. I hope, I can avoid this bad hack somehow. Maybe it's just that I misunderstand some basic concepts of Android like actions, activities, tasks...

Comment: If you do not start a new intent, normally it would not generate a new one. `OnNewIntent` needs to meet some conditions. Different Launch Mode uses the different conditions.

Comment: Zang But there must be a safe way to catch the clipboard data or file uri in an event somehow. ``OnResume`` doesn't get neither. Where can I find an exhaustive documentation of all the conditions and states I need to consider to just get the data?

Comment: Android provides `ClipboardManager`. Check the document for more details. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

Using `SingleTop` launch mode is correct. The reason that `OnNewIntent()` is not being called is that you have declared it like this:

```
protected virtual void OnNewIntent()
```

That isn't correct. The signature is wrong. You need to declare it like this:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
```